# Não fechar Bootstrap dropdown automaticamente

Tags: bootstrap-4

Tenho um Bootstrap dropdown onde uma lista dinâmica é carregada quando o usuário abre o mesmo. O problema é que cada vez que existe uma iteração, por exemplo quando o usuário apaga um item da lista, o dropdown é fechado. Quero que o dropdown seja fechado somente quando o usuário clica no botão para fechar o mesmo.

Como evitar que em cada iteração o dropdown seja fechado automaticamente?

Código para remover um item da lista.

```
$('#containerNotice').on('click', 'button[data-process="removeNotice"]', function(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();
    var noticeId = $(this).attr('data-notice-id');      
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        crossOrigin:true,   
        type:"post",
        url: 'src/inc/notice/',
        data: { noticeId: noticeId, DataProcess: 'remove' },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            switch(data.status) {                   
                case 'success':                     
                    $('button[data-notice-id="'+noticeId+'"]').prop("disabled", true).css('opacity', '0.2');
                    break;                      
            }       
        }                   
    });         
});
```

Comment: Coloca uma amostra do código para ver como é feita a remoção do item.

Comment: Sam.. editei o post original para inserir o código

Comment: vai que é tuuuuuua @tiosam

Comment: O ideal é postar código que possamos usar para reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Tenta isso meu jovem: `$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-item', function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});`

Comment: Valeu sam.. funcionou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao clicar em um item da lista, ele irá disparar um evento que faz com que o dropdown seja fechado. Para evitar isso, use `event.stopPropagation()` no `document` apontando para a classe dos itens, que no caso é a `.dropdown-item`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-item', function(event){ 
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Isso fará com que não seja disparado outro evento atribuído ao dropdown (*bubbling*) que faz com que ele se feche.

Comment: estou com esse erro, inseri o código acima porém não funcionou... No meu caso eu tenho vários checkbox e queria ter a liberdade de escolher eles sem ter que ficar clicando toda hora no icone do dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Sei que o tópico é antigo mas talvez ainda ajude quem estiver pesquisando esse erro hoje em dia assim como aconteceu comigo.
Mesmo na versão 5.0 do Bootstrap eu também me deparei com este erro.

A dica que eu dou é observar os links das dependências dos arquivos bootstrap.min.js.
No meu caso esse era o problema, muitas vezes além da ordem dos links você pode estar duplicando a dependência e entrando em conflito. Faça testes comentando de 1 por 1 os links e veja qual é o problema.
No meu caso era o link para o arquivo `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` que estava conflitando com o arquivo `bootstrap.min.js`, certifíque-se de deixar o arquivo correto da versão que está utilizando.
Espero ter ajudado. Abraço.

Answer (score -2):

Me deparei com esse mesmo problema e a solução que encontrei foi colocar uma condicional no `style` do dropdown-menu, em que o estado é controlado pelo `onclick` do button "dropdown-toggle".

```
style={{ display: `${this.state.openMenu ? 'block' : 'none'}` }}
```

Comment: Outra alternativa que encontrei na documentação e a mais correta, é usar o `<form>`